# Extra wide image slider on responsive site

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I'm creating a responsive site and I'd like to use a really wide image slider (I'm sure you've seen the type of thing).

What I'd like to happen is for the main site to be, for example, maximum 1,200 pixels wide and use a fluid width. I'd then like the image slider to be, for example, 2,000 pixels wide. On a static site this is relatively straightforward as I could simply give the image slider a negative left margin of -400 pixels to center it. Sadly in the case of a responsive site this isn't possible as that offset needs to be fluid.

I did come across some script that made the offset fluid but this only worked when the screen was wider than the site width (i.e the max width of the main content area). When the window then becomes narrower than this max width the script fails to keep the image slider centered .

Any ideas how this could be written to keep the image slider centered horizontally in the window, whether the users window is wide or narrow?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setMargins() {
        width = $(window).width();
        containerWidth = $("#flexslider_width").width();  
        leftMargin = (containerWidth-width)/2;    
        $("#flexslider_width").css("marginLeft", -leftMargin);    
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setMargins();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            setMargins();    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for any thoughts in advance,

Tom

Comment: Clarify something for me please: When your browser window is 2000px, you want your slider to be 1200px wide and align it in the middle. When your browser window is 1000px, how do you want to display your slider? Resize it to 1000px or keep displaying it at 1200px but *cut* 100px on each side? Or am I misunderstanding you completely?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code?

Comment: You're spot on ThomasBormans, when browser window is 2000px, slider will be 1200px wide and aligned to the middle. When browser window is 1000px, slider should keep displaying at 1200px but cut 100px on each side. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks to roman below for the example that I've adapted to demonstrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwLZWa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I understand now. Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azoRwo

```
.outer{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* Move to the middle of the parent */
  margin-right: -50%; /* Remove that extra width */
  transform: translate(-50%, 0); /* Move left again; No IE8 support*/
  width: 1000px;
  height: 96px;
  border: 2px solid cyan; /* Just useful for debugging */
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rBkbXS3.jpg');
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Basically we move right, then left, using percentages of the parent's width. If you want the same functionality in IE8, you'll have to use JavaScript.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment roman, that's fine when the image slider is also fluid but I need it to be a fixed width. Hopefully this demonstrates the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwLZWa

Comment: thank you, that's really helpful. Any ideas of how to get the translate funtion to work in IE8 with a fluid width? You mention using javascript, any reference info you know of?

Comment: Sure, just calculate the difference between widths and set the left offset to half of that http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwoQmW

Answer (score 0):

Alright, check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEPgLp

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
.image-slider{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.main{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .image-slider {
        width: 800px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -400px;
        top: 0;
    }
    .main {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
}
```

When your window is smaller than 800px (was easier to develop. just change the values), I'll position your slider absolute and in the middle. Because of the absolute position, your .main div will move to the top so I'll add a margin-top. Just change your margin-top to the hight of your slider. Good luck!